# Is there any performance benefit when we use Limit

Tags: google-bigquery, database-performance

for example

```
    SELECT company_ID, totalRevenue 
FROM `BigQuery.BQdataset.companyperformance` 
ORDER BY totalRevenue LIMIT 10
```

The only difference I can see between using and not using LIMIT 10 is just the different amount of data used for displaying to user.
The system still orders all the data first before performing a LIMIT.

Comment: This may be of some help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is applicable for BigQuery

Not necessarily 100% technically correct - but close enough so I hope below will give you an idea why LIMIT N is extremely important to consider in BigQuery

Assume you have 1,000,000 rows of data and 8 workers to process query like below

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_1000000_rows ORDER BY some_field
```

Round 1: To sort this data each worker gets 125,000 rows – so now you have 8 sorted sets of 125,000 rows each
Round 2: Worker #1 sends its sorted data (125,000 rows) to worker #2, #3 sends to #4 and so on. So now we have 4 workers and each produce ordered set of 250,000 rows
Round 3: Above logic repeated and now we have just 2 workers each producing ordered list of 500,000 rows
Round 4: And finally, just one worker producing final ordered set of 1,000,000 rows

Of course, based on number of rows and number of available workers – number of rounds can be different than in above example

In Summary: what we have here:
a.  We have quite a huge amount of data being transferred between workers – this can be quite a factor for performance going down
b.  And we have chance for one of the workers not being able to process amount of data distributed to respective worker. It can happen earlier or later and is usually manifested with “Resources exceeded …” type of error

So, now if you have LIMIT as a part of query as below

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_1000000_rows ORDER BY some_field LIMIT 10
```

So, now – Round 1 is going to be the same. But starting with Round 2 – ONLY top 10 rows will be sent to another worker – thus in each Round after first one  - only 20 rows will processed and only top 10 will be sent for further processing
Hope you see how different these two processes in terms of volume of the data being sent between workers and how much work each worker needs to apply to sort respective data

To Summarize:
Without LIMIT 10:
 •  Initial rows moved (Round 1): 1,000,000;
 •  Initial rows ordered (Round 1): 1,000,000;
 •  Intermediate rows moved (Round 2 - 4): 1,500,000
 •  Overall merged ordered rows (Round 2 - 4): 1,500,000;
 •  Final result: 1,000,000 rows

With LIMIT 10:
 •  Initial rows moved (Round 1): 1,000,000;
 •  Initial rows ordered (Round 1): 1,000,000;
 •  Intermediate rows moved (Round 2 - 4): 70
 •  Overall merged ordered rows (Round 2 - 4): 140;
 •  Final result: 10 rows

Hope above numbers clearly show the difference in performance you gain using LIMIT N and in some cases even ability to successfully run the query without "Resource exceeded ..." error

Comment: Nice explanation! So each slot can max handle 10 records instead of all every time after first round of sorting

Comment: I think, you've got the idea :o)

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are asking about the difference between the following two variants:

```
ORDER BY totalRevenue
ORDER BY totalRevenue LIMIT 10
```

In many databases, if a suitable index existed involving `totalRevenue`, the `LIMIT` query could stop sorting after finding the top 10 records.

In the absence of any index, as you pointed out, both versions would have to do a full sort, and therefore should perform the same.

Also, there is a potentially major performance difference between the two, if the table be large.  In the `LIMIT` version, BigQuery only has to send across 10 records, while in the non `LIMIT` version, potentially much more data has to be sent.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly my question is. When you mentioned data to be sent after LIMIT, you mean the output data "displayed" to the user right? The only difference will be rendering the output results into the UI if we are not talking about cache the result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance gain. bigQuery still has go through all the records on the table.

You can partition your data in order to cut the amount of records that bigQuery has to read. That will increase performance. You can read more information here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Answer (score 0):

See the statistical difference in bigQuery UI between the below 2 queries

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` LIMIT 1000
```

[image: Limit 1000]

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments` LIMIT 10000
```

[image: Limit 10000]

As you can see BQ will return immediately to UI after the limit criteria is reached this result in better performance and less traffic on the network

Comment: Yes. But if we have ORDER BY clause, it looks like there is no difference between using Limit and not using Limit because you still need to sort all the data.

Comment: This is not correct since BQ will order up to the Limit and will return the response instead of sorting the entire results. As you can see in the example I provide 2.4sec for limit 1000 and 3.6 sec for 10000